# AngularJS: How to use html-decode for textarea to decode special characters

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to decode  special characters in the  text area   using   html decode

Have  defined  this in the   angularJS   module

```
angular.module('app').filter('htmldecode', function(){
return function(encodedHtml) {
    return angular.element('<textarea>').html(encodedHtml).text();
};
```

How  would  I implement   it in the  HTML?

```html
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'disabled': confirmDeleteCheck}">

    <label for="editReportNotes">Report Notes</label>
    <div >
    <textarea
      name="editReportNotes"
      class="edit-report-notes"
      ng-readonly="!superuser"
      ng-model="editProduct.product.reportNotes "
     
     ng-click="forceCursorToTextEndOnClick( $event, !superuser || confirmDeleteCheck )">{{"editProduct.product.reportNotes" }}
     </textarea>

     <p class="subtext">Looking for Customer Notes?<br>Access on the Product/Survey detail page.</p>

     <p ng-show="editableSurveyForm.editReportNotes.$error.required && submitted" class="error-message">Please enter report notes.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
```

for  `{{"editProduct.product.reportNotes" }}`  so that  all entries in the  text area  is decoded?

Comment: Did you tried using a custom filter ? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: yes  I tried the  filter  defined    above in the   module  as {{"editProduct.product.reportNotes | htmldecode" }} but it does not work